# Unable to set default value in select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I am having an issue with having one of my pages (designed to allow a user to edit a case) have the default value set as what the case details originally were.

In other words the in the event where this particular case already exists and a user wishes to edit the information - I am struggling to pull through values for the dropdown info and have that set as the default value in the edit page

I have tried solving this with 0 luck and not a lot if any info from the console

part of the html this is using:

HTML:

```
<div id="edit-form-left-container">
                        <h4>Customer</h4>
                        <select id="edit-case-form-select-customer">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#edit-case-form-select-customer').select2({
                                    placeholder: "Select a customer",
                                    allowClear: false,
                                    width: '100%',
                                    dropdownParent: $('#edit-form-left-container')
                                });
                            });
```

JS

```
function load_case_info_for_editing_response() {
    let current_case = JSON.parse(this.responseText)[0];


    document.getElementById('edit-case-title').value = current_case.case_title;
    // This is where the issue lies:
    $('#edit-case-form-select-customer').val(current_case.customer).select2(change);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-customer-forename").value = current_case.customer_forename;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-customer-surname").value = current_case.customer_surname;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-alternate-email").value = current_case.alternate_email;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-alternate-phone").value = current_case.alternate_phone;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-case-description").value = current_case.case_description;



    console.log(current_case);
}
```

TBC - the dropdown does work - it just doesn't have a default value set and I don't know what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

So in your case you need to do:

```
    const dropdown = $('#edit-case-form-select-customer');
    dropdown.val(current_case.customer).trigger('change');
    //If above does not work try:
    //dropdown.val(current_case.customer).trigger('change.select2');
```